# regular expression where the value must contain Letters, blank space and numbers

Tags: regex, oracle11g

How to get a regular expression to define if the value contain Letters, blank space and numbers.

NOTE: The value must contain letters, numbers and blank space.

eg.

```
Maalderijstraat 45            Valid
Tronestraat                   Not Valid
Tronesttart45                 Not Valid
123456                        Not Valid
```

I' using this query:

```
select a.street
from clients a 
where REGEXP_LIKE (a.street,'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$')
```

Comment: Seeing as it's probably SQL? I'd say `like '%[A-Za-z]% %[0-9]%'` would suffice?

Comment: I'm using REGEXP_LIKE function.

Comment: (I see you're getting downvotes, probably because this is very trivial and you don't show what you've tried so far)

Comment: Give the exact query you've tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're regex doesn't contain any spaces and if you put them all in the same "class" (the thing between `[]`) then only 1 of them has to match, so if every character matches `a-z` then it matches even though there wasn't a number in it.

Again I doubt you need regex for this:

```
select a.street
from clients a 
where a.street like '[A-Za-z]% %[0-9]'
```

But I suppose you could:

```
select a.street
from clients a 
where REGEXP_LIKE (a.street,'^[a-zA-Z ]+ [0-9]+$')
```

Comment: This answers a different question. The question does not specify any order for the numbers/spaces/letters, just that it must contain at least one of each.

Comment: That's true, I inferred it from the fact that these are Dutch street names (Dutch myself) which use this format. Indeed for French street names this wouldn't work as they often put the house number first.

Answer (score 1):

```
  (?=.*?[ ].*?)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z]+.*?)(?=.*?[0-9]+.*?)(.*)
```

Look at the demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nW8dX7/2

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, but can be simplified to `(?=.* )(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*`.

Comment: yeah right.just wanted it to be more understandble. :)